# MySQL only imports a single row from CSV

Tags: sql, mysql, csv, import

Development machine is a Mac. I'm having some trouble importing more than a single line from a CSV into Mysql. Here is my SQL statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.csv' 
INTO TABLE students
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(pita, dob, name, grd, asst, loc);
```

It runs fine, but only one record is imported. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check the line endings:

```
head -n2 sql.sql | hexdump -C
```

but the most common problem, the line terminator isn't what you'd expect, try:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
```

Comment: +1. The Mac line-terminating character is a carriage return, not a line feed.

Comment: Thank you, Mark L and BipedalShark! That was it.

Comment: Same thing happened to me. It turns out Mac uses '\n' as a line terminator however in mysql I have to use '\r' to import all my records correctly. This is so weird, I guess mysql replaced those characters when it was reading the csv.