# how to import dbf file to mysql without using any paid tools ?

Tags: mysql, import, dbf

How to import dbf file to mysql without using any paid tools ? or else using any stored procedure we can import the data from dbf file to **MYSQL** ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is easy and possible. In case of Linux you should already have Open Office installed and you can download it from http://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html for free and install on you computer with Mac OS X or any Windows operating system.

Open Calc can simply open `dbf` file and save as CSV.

You have to create a table with fields related to CSV and run some import procedure like described here [MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE only imports a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614519/mysql-load-data-local-infile-only-imports-a-single-row)

There are many challenges related to type of data, length of data, escaping some characters but those are beyond such short answer and would require insight into actual data. I prefer to transform CSV in editor to SQL INSERT command to avoid some pitfalls and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Get the description of dbf files (wotsit.org ...), write a small program interpreting the header of the dbf to write a fixed length record (really easy, because DBF files ARE - beside the header - fixed length records) or a comma delimited file and import this to any DB you want.